# Fetch data from multiple table using UNION

Tags: zend-framework2

```
("SELECT * FROM (
    select id, title, report_date, report_file, company,  'company' as report_type from rs_company_report
    union
    select id, title, report_date, report_file, company, 'sector' as report_type from rs_sector_report
    union
    select id, title, report_date, report_file, company, 'morning' as report_type from rs_morning_report) as company_reports where company LIKE '%1%' order by title ");
```

How can I convert this query into zend tablegateway format.

Comment: please post the table schema.

Comment: Question edited with schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Zend2 doesn't provide any UNION support so far.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html#zend-db-sql-select

Answer (score 0):

It now has combine()

But it doesn't work for these two:

- More than two SELECT's
- ORDER